# Stratified sampling in Google Earth Engine

Tags: random, sampling

I am trying to get stratified random points out of GHSL (**G**lobal **H**uman **S**ettlement **L**ayer) which is a classified raster over my study area (partially Europe and Asia continent), see the picture below.

I face multiple errors like computation time out.

Here is the code:

```js
var ghsl  = ee.Image('JRC/GHSL/P2016/BUILT_LDSMT_GLOBE_V1')
var ghsl1 = ghsl.clip(aoi).select('built')


var masked = ghsl1.updateMask((ghsl1.eq(1)).or(ghsl1.eq(2)).or(ghsl1.eq(5)).or(ghsl1.eq(6)));
var ghsl2 = masked.remap([1,2,5,6],[0,1,2,2])
print(masked)

var ghsl5 = ee.Image(masked);
print(ghsl5)

print('Projection, crs, and crs_transform:', ghsl5.projection());

var stratified = ghsl5.addBands(ee.Image.pixelLonLat())
    .stratifiedSample({
      numPoints: 1000,
      classBand: 'built',
      projection: 'EPSG:3857',
      scale: 38,
      region: features.geometry()
    }).map(function(f) {
      return f.setGeometry(ee.Geometry.Point([f.get('longitude'), f.get('latitude')]))
    })

print (stratified.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram(),['class']));
Map.addLayer(stratified);
```

[image: map of Global Human Settlement Layer]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which explains how our Focused question/Best answer model operates. You really need to specify what exact error you want addressed rather than just stating multiple errors occur.